# OllyDbg Labelling

Tags: ollydbg

As you know, OllyDbg provides labelling. When I see referenced address which assembly code has, I would get information(Label name) if referenced address is labeled.
But If labeled address would be referenced indirectly(e.g. mov eax, dword ptr[eax]) or labelled address is stack, OllyDbg cannot show label to reverser. (also, Status bar which is below CPU cannot show label too)
Is there other way to view label in OllyDbg? It's too hard to analyze obfuscated code because of this poooor behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try OllyDBG 2.01 ? It correctly shows the label in the status bar below the CPU for me.

[image: CPU status bar with a label]

Comment: I'm wondering if I can see all the memory label I've added. So I can just click there. I can search of course, but I'd have to type.